# No Activity found to handle Intent act=com.android.camera.action.CROP

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to implement a function to pick a photo from android built-in gallery (not from SD card) or taking a photo using camera. After the image is picked it will be cropped by the user. An ImageView will also be updated with the cropped image. Now after picking an image from gallery, I cannot crop it -- "No Activity found to handle Intent act=com.android.camera.action.CROP" error was returned. And I also can't seem to update the ImageView with the selected image. Can someone please tell me what was wrong? Thanks.

My code is as follows:

```
private void ShowPickDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Add Photo")
            .setNegativeButton("Select from Photos", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),3);
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Take a Pic", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri
                            .fromFile(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                                    "image.jpg")));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                }
            }).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            startPhotoZoom(data.getData());
            break;
        case 2:
            File temp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/test.jpg");
            startPhotoZoom(Uri.fromFile(temp));
            break;
        case 3:
            if(data != null){
                setPicToView(data);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


public void startPhotoZoom(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
}


private void setPicToView(Intent picdata) {
    Bundle extras = picdata.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
        //update ImageView with selected image
        mPic.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

Comment: The com.android.camera.action.CROP action is part of the Internal API and thus won't work in all cases. Just wanted to mention that :) more Details -http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: or you can try to setclass name with crop intent like .. Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");

Answer (score 0):

Android Does **Not** Have a Crop Intent

you can use libraries instead

[Android CropImage](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage)